# Running a Flask app on an IBM i results in error "Can't start new thread"

Tags: python, flask, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I use an IBM i at work and can successfully run basic Python scripts, but can't run a Flask app. When I run the app it appears to launch, but when browsing to the app in my browser, the app throws errors about not being able to start a new thread. I'm guessing this is something related to the IBM i and not Python or Flask.

```
from flask import Flask                                                                                                            
import ibm_db_dbi as db2                                                                                                           
app = Flask(__name__)                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                   
@app.route('/<username>')                                                                                                          
def get_email(username):                                                                                                           
    return f'Hello {username}!'
```

I run this app from Qshell like this:

```
export PATH=/QOpenSys/pkgs/bin:$PATH
export FLASK_APP=index.py
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

This is the output on the console:

[image]

When I browse to the route, this is the error I get:

[image]

I tried running another example with Bottle https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/ and this one seems to work.  I assume that Bottle is not trying to start a new thread.  I would ideally like to get it working with Flask though.

Comment: Can you share some code? How do you run the flask app? Where does the error happen?  If it has a line of code in the error that might help narrow it down

Comment: I've added my app code and how the app is being run.  The error occurs as soon as I browse to the route.

Comment: Can you post the error you got?

Comment: I've added more details of the console output when running the app and then the error output when browsing to the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which Python you're running, hopefully the recommended 3.6 installed via `yum`.

But sounds like you don't have multi-threading enabled...

> QIBM_MULTI_THREADED (Start multi-thread capable processes) This
> variable determines if processes started by qsh can create multiple
> threads. When the value of the variable is "Y", all child processes
> started by qsh can start threads. The default value is "N".
>
> ```
>                  Change Environment Variable (CHGENVVAR)
> ```
>
> Type choices, press Enter.
>
> Environment variable . . . . . . > QIBM_MULTI_THREADED
>
> New value  . . . . . . . . . . .   Y

Comment: Thanks Charles, yes I’m running 3.6 installed with Yum through ACS.  Should I be worried about any performance issues or resource issues if I enable multi threading?  Also, once I learned a bit more about running a Python web app, I was able to launch my app using Gunicorn behind Nginx and I’m not running into any thread issues yet.

Comment: From what little I know, it shouldn't be a problem.  Also environment variables can be set for the job or globally.   So you could just start with the job level.